# How do I all the eclipse(Galileo version) help installed on my local machine?

Tags: eclipse

Currrently, all the topics that are listed in http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp are not installed on my machine. I understand that help is only installed for the plugins that are installed already. However, I see that PDE(Plugin Development) API reference is not installed on my local eclipse, though a overview of PDE is.

Basically, I want to have a local copy of whatever is on eclipse help site . How do I get that in HTML format?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Help -> Install New Software...`  Choose Galileo in the "Work with" list.  Uncheck `Group items by category` and in the filter box type "doc".

When I do this in Helios, I see a list of about 40 different documentation features that can be installed.  I would guess it would be similar when working with Galileo.

There is no particular guarantee that this is all the docs from what is on the site, but it is likely a large portion of it.

After installing the docs this way, everything is available from Help -> Help Contents.  The html will be in the doc jars under the eclipse/plugins folder.